# Python run flask on https with port 80

Tags: python, flask, browser

I'm trying to run my flask app on localhost with https and port 80. It works, but turns out I need to specify the port in the browser url when navigating to the app.
So, if I go to https://localhost on my browser, the app doesn't show, but if I go to https://localhost:80 the page works.
Is there a way to reach the app without specifying the port when typing the url? Shoudln't it be **80** by default when I don't specify the port?
Thanks in advance!

I'm expecting to reach the website without needing to specify the port when it is 80.

Comment: Try going to `http://localhost` instead of `https`. Port 80 is the default port for http and not for https.

Comment: The page still doesn't show

Comment: `flask app on localhost with https`, if this means you have set up some kind of https try changing the port that you are hosting the app on to 443. 443 being the default port for https. And then going to `https://localhost`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are running your app on port 80(default port for http) with https configured.

When accessing `https://localhost` the browser tries to access the port 443 (the default port for https), while your app is hosted on port 80.

Changing the hosting port to 443 should allow you to access `https://localhost` without specifying the port.